# Sorting algorithm to keep equal values separated

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Psychology experiments often require you to pseudo-randomize the trial order, so that the trials are apparently random, but you don't get too many similar trials consecutively (which could happen with a purely random ordering).

Let's say that the visual display on each trial has a colour and a size:

```
display_list = []
colours = {0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green', 3: 'yellow'}
sizes = [1] * 20 + [2] * 20 + [3] * 20 + [4] * 20 + [5] * 20 + [6] * 20
for i in range(120):
    display_list.append({'colour': colours[i % 4], 'size': sizes[i]})
print(display_list)
```

And we can look at the maximum number of consecutive trials that has the same value for either property using this function:

```
def consecutive_properties(seq, field):
    longest_run = 0
    prev_value = None
    current_run = 0
    for d in seq:
        if d[field] == prev_value:
            current_run += 1
        else:
            current_run = 1
        if current_run > longest_run:
            longest_run = current_run
        prev_value = d[field]
    return longest_run
```

Output:

```
>>> print("Consecutive colours: ", consecutive_properties(display_list, 'colour')
('Consecutive colours: ', 1)

>>> print("Consecutive sizes: ", consecutive_properties(display_list, 'size'))
('Consecutive sizes: ', 20)
```

Are there any algorithms you know of that would allow minimizing the consecutive runs of either or both properties, or at least keep these runs below a specified length? If the latter, let's say no more than 4 in a row of the same colour or size.

---

What I've tried:

The solution I have now basically does a slightly intelligent [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), which has to be horribly inefficient. Basically:

- You break the entire list into chunks containing all the permutations of the properties: if you break down `display_list` into chunks of length 24, each chunk has each colour paired with each size. Let's assume that the trial list can always be broken down into these permutation chunks, since you know what the permutations are from the design of the experiment.
- You choose a maximum run length per chunk
- You shuffle each chunk until the run lengths for each chunk are below the maximum value (this actually means that in the overall trial list, your runs might be double that length, since you could have a run of this length at the end of one chunk and the start of the next)

Comment: For one property, 1) sort by property 2) within equal values, shuffle (shuffle all reds, shuffle all yellows, etc) 3) (Slightly randomly?) Alternate adding colours into a new list such that you try to keep the % taken of each colour equal (e.g. if you have four reds and two blues you'd take a red and a blue, then another red to bring it to 50%, etc). Then for a second property, you could prioritize taking from lists of colours to try and not make runs of the second property, something like that.

Comment: So you require that the number of occurrences of each permutation is equal overall?

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes, since I think that makes the problem more well-defined. I'm trying to keep constraints on the question so that it stays a tricky but hopefully interesting CompSci brainteaser, rather than just a muddle. In the real world, where I'm a research assistant in a psychology lab, the constraints are usually "whatever the professor wants to squeeze into the experiment".

Comment: Does you actual sample have the same likelihood of getting more than 4 consecutive fields in a row as in the example?

Comment: @root: The actual experiment I'm working on at the moment has this 4 x 6 structure, which made it easier to solve with my basic bogosort approach, but there are probably a lot of experiments where the probability of having a large consecutive run would be higher, e.g. you might have a 3 x 4 structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question:  Are there any algorithms you know of that would allow minimizing the
>   consecutive runs of either or both properties, or at least keep these
>   runs below a specified length?

Yes.  There is an easy algorithm for doing this by simply reducing the probability of a color or size being chosen if it is already occurring in a run.

```
from random import randrange

def choose(colors, numselections, maxrun):
    'Repeatedly choose colors.  Gradually reduce selection probability to avoid runs.'
    colors = list(colors)
    n = len(colors)
    total = n * maxrun
    current_run = 0
    for _ in range(numselections):
        i = randrange(total - current_run) // maxrun
        yield colors[i]
        colors[i], colors[-1] = colors[-1], colors[i]
        current_run = current_run + 1 if i==n-1 else 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
    for color in choose(colors, 100, maxrun=4):
        print color
```

Note, this approach requires less effort than the other answers which use reselection techniques to avoid runs.  Also, note the runs are faded-out gradually rather than all at once as in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly not concerned with anything like true randomness, so if you define a distance metric, and draw your sequence randomly, you can reject any new draw if it's distance is "too close" to the previous draw, and simply draw again.

If you're drawing from a finite set (say, a pack of cards) then the whole set can
be the draw pile, and your sort would consist of swapping two elements when a close
pair is found, but also reject a swap partner if the swapped element would become unacceptable, so each swap step leaves the whole set improved.

If your criteria are not too hard to satisfy, this will terminate very quickly.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely an approach I haven't tried yet. Would you be able to give an example of what the distance metric might be for the colour/size example?

Comment: Marius In this case, you'd reject a draw if it forms a run of K with the previous K-1 draws.

Comment: something like (color_a==color_b)?0:1 + (size_a==size_b) ? 0 : 1

Answer (score 1):

As [ddyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16767059/497208) said, you are interested in randomness rather than sorting. My solution here would be:

1. Pick a random A element from your source list
2. Pick a random position I from your destination list
3. Insert A at position I to dest. list
4. Check if the destination list is valid. If not, restore the previous state and repeat

A working snippet:

```
from random import randint
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice

def reshuffle(_items, max_consequent):
    items = _items[:]
    new_order = []
    while items:
        src_pos = randint(0, len(items)-1)
        dest_pos = randint(0, len(new_order))
        item = items[src_pos]
        new_order.insert(dest_pos, item)
        if is_new_order_fine(new_order, max_consequent):
            items.pop(src_pos)
        else:
            new_order.pop(dest_pos)
    return new_order

def is_new_order_fine(items, n_max):
    return (
        not has_consecutive_keys(items, n_max, key=itemgetter('colour')) and
        not has_consecutive_keys(items, n_max, key=itemgetter('size')))

# can be optimised - don't check all items, just surrounding N
def has_consecutive_keys(items, n_max, key):
    _has_n_keys = False
    if len(items) >= n_max:
        last_value = key(items[0])
        n_consequent = 1
        for item in items[1:]: # can optimize by using iterator
            if key(item) == last_value:
                n_consequent += 1
            else:
                last_value = key(item) 
                n_consequent = 1
            if n_consequent >= n_max:
                _has_n_keys = True
                break
    return _has_n_keys
```

Note that you don't need to check all items in the destination list each time, K on the left and right around the inserted new item (not implemented in the snippet)

**Edit**:

- You can use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in `has_consecutive_keys` (but without sorting!)

Answer (score 1):

If the likelihood of consecutive elements is not very high (as in your example), I would simply reshuffle if the condition is not met. As you can see, most of the time you get away with one try, so it is quite efficient.

```
In [1]: from random import shuffle

In [2]: from itertools import groupby

In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: def pseudo_shuffle(lst, limit, tries=1):
   ...:     temp = list(lst)
   ...:     shuffle(temp)
   ...:     if max(sum(1 for x in g) for k, g in groupby(temp)) <= limit:
   ...:         return tries #return temp
   ...:     return pseudo_shuffle(lst, limit, tries=tries+1)

In [5]: colors = 30*['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

In [6]: sizes = [1] * 20 + [2] * 20 + [3] * 20 + [4] * 20 + [5] * 20 + [6] * 20

In [7]: Counter([pseudo_shuffle(colors, 4) for _ in range(1000)])
Out[7]: Counter({1: 751, 2: 200, 3: 38, 4: 10, 5: 1})

In [8]: Counter([pseudo_shuffle(sizes, 4) for _ in range(1000)])
Out[8]: Counter({1: 954, 2: 44, 3: 2})
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew my particular case was probably not too hard, but having this kind of analysis of how hard the constraints are to satisfy for a given limit is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not an answer, but it's hard to post code in comments. Here is a simpler way to write the `consecutive_properties` function

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
def consecutive_properties(seq, field):
    return max(sum(1 for x in g) for k,g in groupby(seq, key=itemgetter(field)))
```

When I understand your question properly I'll try to turn this into an answer :)

Comment: He wants to pick a random shuffle such that the maximum run length (where a run length can be of one property out of p1, p2, p3... pn of consecutive elements being equal) is below K.

Comment: Yeah, let me know if any particular parts of the question are unclear, but @Patashu's summary is pretty much it. As for the pythonicity of the `consecutive_properties` function, I've been working in MATLAB lately, and my brain was only slowly turning back on as I tried to write up the example. Thanks :)